# Preserving QgsLayerTreeViewIndicator on moving node in layer tree with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, icon, qgslayertree

I am using the script below to display an icon next to my layer in the layer tree view, which works fine. However, when a user moves the position of that node, the indicator disappears.

```py
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "my layer", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, False)

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
node_layer1 = root.addLayer(layer1)

indicator = QgsLayerTreeViewIndicator(iface.layerTreeView())
indicator.setToolTip('Test')
indicator.setIcon(QIcon(':/images/themes/default/mActionIdentify.svg'))
indicator.clicked.connect(lambda: print('indicator clicked'))

iface.layerTreeView().addIndicator(node_layer1, indicator)
```

How would I preserve the indicator and the connected action, so that it can be triggered even after moving the node?

*Some context on what I additionally tried so far:*

I tried to listen for the [`QAbstractItemModel.rowsMoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved) signal, to identify when the node is moved and then again re-add the indicator afterwards.

But it seems that *only* this specific signal is not emitted by `QgsLayerTreeModel`.

Another thing I tried is listening to the `rowsInserted` signals to detect if my created node has been inserted at a different position, in order to then again re-add the indicator. But that also does not work, because on moving the node the original object gets deleted. So if I try to add the indicator with `iface.layerTreeView().addIndicator(node_layer1, indicator)` it complains about a

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsLayerTreeLayer has been
> deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the code below:

```py
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "my layer", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, False)

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
node = root.addLayer(layer1)

indicator = QgsLayerTreeViewIndicator(iface.layerTreeView())
indicator.setToolTip('Test')
indicator.setIcon(QIcon(':/images/themes/default/mActionIdentify.svg'))
indicator.clicked.connect(lambda: print('indicator clicked'))

view = iface.layerTreeView()

view.addIndicator(node, indicator)

def rows_inserted(parent, first, last):
    nodes = root.findLayers()
    for n in nodes:
        if n.layer().id() == layer1.id():
            if not view.indicators(n):
                view.addIndicator(n, indicator)

conn = view.layerTreeModel().rowsInserted.connect(rows_inserted)
```

After removing layer, clean up by disconnecting signal/slot and deleting indicator object:

```py
QObject.disconnect(conn)
del indicator
```

Screencast shows this working:

[image]

Based very loosely on source code in [qgslayertreeviewindicatorprovider.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2d1aa68f0d044f2aced7ebeca8d2fa6b754ac970/src/app/qgslayertreeviewindicatorprovider.cpp) which would probably take care of this nicely but does not seem to be exposed in the Python API bindings.

Comment: Well done, Ben W.

Comment: @Germán Carrillo, thank you! :-)